# Working with MVC3 @using to display a control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have this piece of code in a .cshtml.

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("CheckoutShippingAddress", FormMethod.Post))
{
 <div class="enter-address-body">
 @{
 var dataDictPatient = new ViewDataDictionary();
 dataDictPatient.ModelState.Merge(ViewData.ModelState);
 dataDictPatient.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "PatientInformation";
  @Html.Partial("_CreateOrUpdateAddress", Model.PatientRoom, dataDictAddress)              
  }
```

what is happening is an error

`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Models.Common.PatientModel', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Models.Common.AddressModel'.`

what i don't understand is i changed the dictionary to want patientmodel and not addressmodel.

Comment: The code you posted has nothing to do with the error.  The error is being caused by the @model statement at the top of the page.

Comment: Agreed, what you have there works fine - but you need to change the model statement.

Comment: Can you show your action method and model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the `PatientRoom` property of your model is declared as a `PatientModel` (eg. you didn't just change the *name* to `PatientRoom` but leave the type as `AddressModel`, and also that the @model statement at the top of your `_CreateOrUpdateAddress` model is `@model PatientModel`.